# Java HiLow percent chance calculator -- Apparent Logic Issue

Tags: java, probability, playing-cards

I'm having some difficulty with a Java-based probability calculator for an iteration of a HiLow game (specifically this one: http://bitino.com/hi-lo/). The objective of the program is to statistically suggest a bet given a `CHANCE_THRESHOLD` value. The program also keeps track of cards played. The issue I am running into has to do with the chance calculations. Thus far I have successfully addressed the values of 'A' (an Ace) but have run into issue testing other values. Evidently there must be something wrong with logic behind the valuation of percent chance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HiLow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String flip = "";
        double flipInt = 0.0;

        final double CHANCE_THRESHOLD = 0.75;
        double chanceLower = 0;
        double chanceHigher = 0;

        String cardArray[] = { "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K" };
        int cardValue[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 };

        int cardCounter[] = { 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 };

        int remainingCards = 0;

        while (!(flip.equalsIgnoreCase("e"))) {

            for (int x = 0; x < cardCounter.length; x++) {
                cardCounter[x] = 4;
            }

            chanceLower = 0;
            chanceHigher = 0;

            System.out.print(" > ");
            flip = scan.next();

            while (!(flip.equalsIgnoreCase("r")) && !(flip.equalsIgnoreCase("e"))) {

                for (int x = 0; x < 13; x++) {
                    if (flip.equalsIgnoreCase(cardArray[x])) {
                        flipInt = cardValue[x];
                        cardCounter[x]--;
                    }
                }

                remainingCards = 0;
                for (int x = 0; x < cardCounter.length; x++) {
                        remainingCards = remainingCards + cardCounter[x];
                }

                chanceLower = (((flipInt) - 1) + cardCounter[(int) (flipInt - 1)]) / remainingCards;
                System.out.println((((flipInt) - 1) + cardCounter[(int) (flipInt - 1)]) + " / " + remainingCards + " = " + chanceLower);

                // This line should output 0.98039215686 given the input of 'a'
                //chanceHigher = ((13 - (flipInt)) + cardCounter[(int) (flipInt - 1)]) / remainingCards;
                //System.out.println(((13 - (flipInt)) + cardCounter[(int) (flipInt - 1)]) + " / " + remainingCards + " = " + chanceHigher);

                chanceHigher = Math.abs(1 - chanceLower);
                System.out.println(Math.abs((((flipInt) - 1) + cardCounter[(int) (flipInt - 1)]) - remainingCards) + " / " + remainingCards + " = " + chanceHigher);


                if (chanceLower > chanceHigher) {
                    if (chanceLower >= CHANCE_THRESHOLD) {
                        System.out.println("Bet Lower.");
                    } else if (chanceLower > (CHANCE_THRESHOLD - 0.10)){
                        System.out.println("Bet with Caution.");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Risk Outside Threshold.");
                    }

                } else {
                    if (chanceHigher >= CHANCE_THRESHOLD) {
                        System.out.println("Bet Higher.");
                    } else if (chanceHigher > (CHANCE_THRESHOLD - 0.10)){
                        System.out.println("Bet with Caution.");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Risk Outside Threshold.");
                    }
                }

                for (int x = 0; x < cardCounter.length; x++) {
                    System.out.print(cardCounter[x] + ":" + cardArray[x] + " ");
                }
                System.out.print("\n");

                System.out.print(" > ");
                flip = scan.next();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

As always, help is greatly appreciated. Thank you ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, You are not closing the scanner, but I guess that it's just been overlooked.

Secondly remainingCards is is not enough. For once, you shouldn't count remaining cards of the same value - these are not higher nor lower, just the same.

There is no need to calculate whole array of greater / lower cards, 2 variables are enough

```
remainingLowerCards = 0;
remainingHigherCards = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < cardCounter.length; x++) {
    remainingCards = remainingCards + cardCounter[x];
    if (x < flipInt - 1) {
        remainingLowerCards += cardCounter[x];
    } else if (x >= flipInt) {
        remainingHigherCards += cardCounter[x];
    }
}

chanceLower = ((double) remainingLowerCards) / remainingCards;
System.out.println("Lower: " + remainingLowerCards + " / " + remainingCards + " = " + chanceLower);

// This line should output 0.98039215686 given the input of 'a'
chanceHigher = ((double) remainingHigherCards) / remainingCards;
System.out.println("Higher: " + remainingHigherCards + " / " + remainingCards + " = "
        + chanceHigher);
```

Comment: but there is the possibility that the next card drawn could be the same, which is why I do need to count them as lower because in the game I linked, house wins ties. Perhaps I need to put some more thought into this, but thank you very much for your input.

Comment: Exactly what I said - if house wins ties, you mustn't add them to what higher / lower cards are left, because they are neither higher nor lower. Adding them would make calculation flawed. Imagine game with 6 cards: 2x1, 2x2, 2x3. You draw number 2. there is 5 cards left, 2 higher (3), 2 lower (1) and 1 equal (2). Probability of drawing higher is 2/5, and lower is 2/5, 1/5 is the chance to draw the same - but you will still loose. So basically it's 2/5 to win and 3/5 to loose.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the sum of the number of remaining cards BELOW the card value you have (not just determine the total number of remaining cards).  For example, you could use something like

```
int[] cardsBelow = new int[13];
for (int i=0; i < cardsBelow.length; i++) {
  if (i == 0) {
     cardsBelow[i] = cardCounter[i];
  } else {
     cardsBelow[i] = cardsBelow[i-1] + cardCounter[i];
  }
}
```

that way, the cell `cardsBelow[i-1]` contains the number of cards below the "i"th card.

Comment: interesting approach, I'll have to tinker with it the next chance I get.